# c++: работа с битами в массивах

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, c++17

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в новых версиях стандарта c++ или в стандартной библиотеке функционал работы с битами в больших массивах данных.

Например, у меня есть массив

```
char* buffer;
```

в котором надо определить значение n-ого бита (к примеру, 12345ого) или установить такой бит или сбросить.

Сейчас я использую свои функции:

```
uint8_t
get_bit
(
    uint8_t*        buffer
    const uint32_t  index
) const
{
    const uint32_t bytesIndex = index/ 8;
    const uint32_t bitsIndex = index % 8;

    const uint32_t mask = (1 << bitsIndex);

    const uint32_t maskValue = (buffer[bytesIndex] & mask);

    return ((maskValue == 0) ? (0) : (1));
}

void 
set_bit
(
    uint8_t*        buffer
    const uint32_t  index,
    const uint8_t   value 
)
{
    const uint32_t bytesIndex = buffer/ 8;
    const uint32_t bitsIndex = buffer % 8;

    const uint32_t mask = (1 << bitsIndex);

    buffer[bytesIndex] = (value == 1) ? (buffer[bytesIndex] | mask) : (buffer[bytesIndex] & !mask);
}
```

что все таки несколько затрудняет чтение кода :)

Может в C++11+ появились какие-то встроенные средства, более красивые и более быстрые, чем самописное?

Comment: [`bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) не хотите использовать? Или? на худой конец, `vector<bool>`?

Comment: Почему затрудняет? `get_bit` - `set_bit` - все ясно. Единственная проблема в том, что размер массива нигде не передается и выход за его пределы не отслеживается.

Comment: @VTT, это я при копировании кода подчистил излишне :), так то проверка есть. Просто подумал может уже есть встроенные быстрые решения (быстрее моего подхода в лоб)

Comment: @Harry, а мне казалось что вектор `bool` все таки будет выделять по байту на каждый `bool`

Comment: Нет, не будет - он хранит их упакованно, но делает это через ж... в смысле, через прокси.

Comment: Чтобы не создавать лишнюю переменную, можно писать сразу (на примере первого). `return (buffer[bytesIndex] & mask)!=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Современные процессоры быстрее исполняют линейный код, т.е. код не содержащий ветвлений (в т.ч. тернарного оператора).

Поэтому можно предложить, например, вот такие модификации функций проверки и установки бита (можете положить их в какой-либо из ваших заголовочных файлов)

```
static inline int get_bit (uint8_t arr[], size_t bitno) {
  return (arr[bitno >> 3] >> (bitno & 7)) & 1;
}

static inline void set_bit (uint8_t arr[], size_t bitno, int v) {
  arr[bitno >> 3] = (arr[bitno >> 3] & ~(1 << (bitno & 7))) | ((v & 1) <<  (bitno & 7));
}
```

В функции `get_bit()` мы сдвигаем искомый бит в младший бит возвращаемого результата.

В функции `set_bit()` изменяемый бит сначала обнуляется -- `~(1 << (bitno & 7))`, а затем устанавливается в заданный, путем сдвига младшего бита `v` в требуемую позицию -- `(v & 1) <<  (bitno & 7)`.